# How to query parameters with API Gateway to lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I made a REST API with AWS Lambda+ API Gateway.

my API Gateway's `Integration Request` is `LAMBDA_PROXY` Type,

and I use params in Lambda like this. ( `myparam` is list type)

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    try:
        myparam = event['multiValueQueryStringParameters']['param1']
    #...
```

I tested my REST API in python like this.

```
url = 'https://***.amazonaws.com/default/myAPI'

param = {'param1':['1','2']}

res = requests.get(url=url,params=param).json()
print(res)
```

It works. but when I tried with another way like this,

```
url = 'https://***.amazonaws.com/default/myAPI?param1=1,2'

res = requests.get(url=url).json()
print(res)
```

It didn't work with this way.
How to query parameters in case if I want to insert parameter into url directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those tow requests are not equivalent. In order to prove it, we can print the formatted URL for the first request:

```py
url = 'https://***.amazonaws.com/default/myAPI'

param = {'param1':['1','2']}

res = requests.get(url=url,params=param).json()

# Print the request URL
print(res.request.url)
```

This will print something like:

```
https://***.amazonaws.com/myAPI?param1=1&param1=2
```

So, in your second snippet, you probably would want to create your URL as follows:

```py
url = 'https://***.amazonaws.com/myAPI?param1=1&param1=2'

res = requests.get(url=url).json()
print(res)
```

If you want to separate your parameters with commas, the value for `param1` will be a string (`'1,2'`), not an list.